# Play JSON looses time info on deserialise

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have the following code:

```
val test = Json.parse("""{"someDate":"1998-10-18T10:00:00+03:00"}""")
val aDate = (test \ "someDate").as[Date]
val activationDate = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ").parseDateTime("1998-10-18T10:00:00+03:00").toDate
assert(aDate.compareTo(activationDate) == 0)
```

But the dates never compare, actually the 'aDate' has lost it's time info. Anyone here has an answer to me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have seen, the date info is lost when formatted from json. Though I don't know why, I can give an alternative solution to fix your problem. We can know that the `string` parsed from json will keep all its info. so you can parse the json data to be a `String` but not a `Date` and then format the parsed `String` to be what you want. The code is following

```
val aDateString = (test \ "someDate").as[String]//not Date
```

then, format it as usual String to Date

```
val aDate = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ").
            parseDateTime(aDateString).toDate//parse the string parsed from json
```

At this time,

```
assert(aDate.compareTo(activationDate) == 0)
```

will return the right answer.

Because `aDateString` is parsed from json does not lost info, you can implement what you want

Maybe, my solution is not the best, but it can guarantee the date info does not be lost

[The blog](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/11/how-to-serialize-date-and-datetime-without-losing-information/) maybe help you

Good luck

Comment: Looks like there's nothing else to do about it.
I still think it's strange that it doesn't work as expected

Comment: @TomdeVroomen yes, it's something strange, I have searched some answers for the questions like yours, but there is no good explanation.